# Примитивы и объекты в java

Tags: java

По заданию от наставника в коде надо исправить ошибку. Код был:

```
public class Container {
    private Integer count;

    public void addCount(int value) {
        count = count + value;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Я заменил на:

```
public class Container {
    private Integer count = 1;

    public void addCount(int value) {
        count = count + value;
    }

    public int getCount() {
```

Преподаватель написал, что неправильно и написал, что идут операции boxing-а идут, т.к. int конвертируется в Integer - это медленно и занимает излишнюю память. Я переписал код, просто заменив Integer на int. Насколько это правильно? Может есть другие способы?

```
public class Container {
    private int count = 1;

    public void addCount(int value) {
        count = count + value;
    }

    public int getCount() {
```

Класс Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.addCount(200);
        System.out.println(container.getCount());
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Что происходит при работе с примитивами:**

При присвоении примитива в экземпляр объектного типа (класс обертку над примитивом):

```
Integer count = 1;
```

На самом деле происходит следующее:

```
Integer count = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

Другими словами, неявно создается экземпляр класса `Integer`. Эта операция называется auto boxing, т.е. автоматическое обертывание примитива в класс обретку над ним.

Такие классы обертки также называют wrapper'ами:

- `int` обертывается в класс `Integer`;
- `long` - в `Long`;
- и так далее.

**Встроенные оптимизации классов оберток:**

Тем не менее, у класса `Integer` существует некоторый кэш значений, экземпляры которых он создает при старте JVM: `[-128, 127]`.

Иначе говоря, внутри статического метода `valueOf(int value)` класса `Integer` сначала проверяется не входит ли полученный в аргументах `value` в этот интервал кэширования, если входит, то оттуда просто берется ссылка на уже существующий экземпляр объектного типа `Integer`, хранящий необходимое нам значение притививного типа в виде `final int value`, т.е. неизменяемого своего поля.

Переиспользование значений из cache допустимо вследствие того, что все классы обертки (wrapper'ы) над примитивными типами являются неизменяемыми (immutable) вследствие того, что единственное хранимое ими поле имеет модификатор `final`, как следствие инициализируется при создании объекта, после чего не может быть изменено.

**Выводы:**

Классы обертки достаточно хорошо оптимизированы, чтобы не создавать дубли экземпляров объектных классов с одинаковыми значениями в рамках некоторого интервала кеширования.

Тем не менее, если у вас нет реальной необходимости в работе с классами обертками (значение не может быть `null`, и вы не вызываете никакие методы класса обертки), то для экономии ресурсов JVM лучше избегайте их.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, довольно развернуто.